# to input date between start and end date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a method to input a start and end date using user form. How can I input the dates in between this start and end date and provide it as an input in excel sheet using `VBA`?

For example, if my **start date** `1st jan 2012` and my **end date** is `1st april 2012`, I would like to get input in an `excel sheet` in this form :

```
1st jan 2012
1st feb 2012
1st march 2012
1st april 2012
```

Please, suggest me a VBA code to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It s difficult to understand what do you mean but you can try this:

```
Sub test3()

Dim Startdate As Date, EndDate As Date, AdditionalDate As String
Dim DatesDiff As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRowA As Long

Startdate = Format(CDate("01/01/12"), "DD/MM/YYYY")
EndDate = Format(CDate("01/04/12"), "DD/MM/YYYY")

If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Startdate
Else
    LastRowA = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Range("A" & LastRowA + 1).Value = Startdate
End If

DatesDiff = Month(EndDate) - Month(Startdate) - 1

For i = 1 To DatesDiff
    AdditionalDate = Left(CStr(Startdate), 2) & "/" & (Month(CStr(Startdate)) + i) & "/" & Right(CStr(Startdate), 4)
    LastRowA = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Range("A" & LastRowA + 1).Value = CDate(AdditionalDate) 'Format(CDate(AdditionalDate), "DD/MM/YYYY")
Next i
    LastRowA = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Range("A" & LastRowA + 1).Value = EndDate

End Sub
```

Comment: @Aravind SR if the above answer is what you are looking for please vote this answer is usefull by pressing the upper arrow above 0 next to the answer.thanks a lot!